# Chart JS - Horizontal Bar Chart Not Filling Canvas

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a list of stacked, horizontal bar charts that I want to all be the same width.

Each canvas is the same width, and each chart uses the same config (with different data sets, of course).

I've tested a lot of different configuration options, from `barPercentage`, to `categoryPercentage`, to setting `fullWidth` on the Y-Axis.

[**Here is a JSFiddle showing the same issue.**](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/fd4qu0w3)

What am I missing?

```
this.chartConfig = {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
            {
                backgroundColor: this.colors,
                data: this.data,
            },
            highlight_dataset,
        ],
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: { display: false },
        legend: { display: false },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
            },
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [
                {
                    display: false,
                    stacked: true,
                },
            ],
            yAxes: [
                {
                    display: false,
                    stacked: true,
                    beforeFit: (scaleInstance: any) => {
                        scaleInstance.fullWidth = true;
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        events: ['mousemove'],
        onHover: (event: any, chartElement: any) => {
            event.target.style.cursor = chartElement && chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
        },
        tooltips: {
            filter: (tooltipItem: any) => {
                return tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 0;
            },
        },
    },
};
```

[image]

Comment: Add minimal complete and verifyable example.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev I'll work on an example.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev I've updated the answer with a link to JSFiddle.

Comment: Just a quick heads up to future developers: Starting with **chart.js v3.0** the *Horizontal Bar* configuration changes to `chartConfig = { type: 'bar', options: { indexAxis: 'y' } };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max` value for ticks and it will set same maximum value for all charts. [**Here is an updated JSFiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/76nwebcu/)

```
base_options.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.max = max;
```

```
const base_options = {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
            {
                backgroundColor: [],
                data: [],
            }
        ],
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: { display: false },
        legend: { display: false },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
            },
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [
                {
                    display: false,
                    stacked: true,

                }
            ],
            yAxes: [
                {
                    display: false,
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        max: max
                    }
                },
            ],
        },
        events: ['mousemove'],
        onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
            event.target.style.cursor = chartElement && chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
        },
        tooltips: {
            filter: (tooltipItem) => {
                return tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 0;
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: The issue here is that each dataset now has the same max. I intentionally put the `max` variable in the `forEach` because my charts each have a different max. Actually, each chart (in my actual project) has an entirely different scale and are unrelated.

Comment: I don't understand why the max of one `new Chart()` would ever affect the display of another `new Chart()`. They should be entirely separate.

Comment: @WebWanderer they are but if you look from the chart rendering perspective, they decide what should be maximum value for tick on the axis. Alternatively, you can specify max value for the tick as:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofmtjug7/

Comment: YES!!! That did it! The `options.scales.xAxes[n].ticks.max` setting does it! Update your answer and you'll get the rep. Thank you!

Comment: I updated your answer to show only the necessary content, as not to distract the readers. The way the data is formulated is correct, and the `max` value should be set in the `forEach`. The JSFiddle that you provided reflects this. The answer is simply the `max` value on the X-axis.

Comment: Hey @WebWanderer do you know what is going on? Looks like this post was reverted back to some previous version and I was awarded bounty? Time travel is indeed possible on SO, eh!

Comment: @WebWanderer I had asked about it on Meta and looks like may be one of the moderators were monitoring the conversation and he/she made it happen, I guess!

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the categoryPercentage and add the below code

```
var options = {
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        barPercentage: 0.4
    }]
}
```

}

Comment: Why `0.4`? Was this calculated?

Comment: I had given a random number, you can give whichever you want.